# What's the syntax in js of grid-template-rows?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am building a website which has a grid system that looks good on pc and web browsers, but looks trash when i access it on my phone. I thought of a solution that involves writing a condition in the site script file (script.js).

```
if(screen.width<415) {
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = "100px 500px 900px"; 
}
```

In the code above it says that if the width of the screen that the website loads on is smaller than 415 pixels (In simpler words, if I access the website from a Phone, the grid system sizes change.

The following command does not work, so my question is what's the correct syntax for :

```
container.style.gridTemplateRows = "100px 500px 900px";
```

[Website on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh5rA.png)

[Website on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuBwl.png)

I tried using the grid-template-rows style to redefine the sizes of the grid system, so the website would look good on pc and phone at the same time.

The result was none, the command having no effect in the end.

Comment: I would say CSS media queries are better suited for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries